# Send dictionary with python to flask server

Tags: python, post, request

I need to send a dictionary from my raspberry to a flask server (that would be my PC) with a POST request but I have this error:

*requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /events (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xb5a00f90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))*

The code in my raspberry is:

```
import json
import requests

mac_dict = {}

def main():
    readFile()

def readFile():
    with open("/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/device.txt", "r") as file:
        for i in file:
            line, *lines = i.split()
            if line in mac_dict:
                mac_dict[line] += lines
            else:
                mac_dict[line] = lines
    print(mac_dict)
    print("\n")

    json_obj = json.dumps(mac_dict, indent=4)
    with open("/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/mac_addr.json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(json_obj)

    server_ip = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/events'
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    req = requests.post(server_ip, headers=headers, data=json_obj)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I use this function to read a file in raspberry, convert it to a json file and send it to the flask server

And this is the code for flask server:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/json', methods=['POST'])
def jsonPost():
    data = request.json
    print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Replace `127.0.0.1` in your client code with whatever the local IP address is for your PC. You can see this with `ifconfig` on Linux or `ipconfig` on Windows, e.g. `IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.9`.

Comment: Potentially this could be a case of you requiring CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) for it to work. I have had a similar problem with a react application that required cors to interact with the flask server. Look into flask-cors

Comment: CORS shouldn't be a problem if they're using Requests, its more often an issue on browsers.

Comment: Thanks Aidan, now i don't have the error anymore but i can't visualize the dictionary on the web page and I have this error: 405 Method not allowed

Comment: From your server code it doesn't look like you have a `/events` endpoint, try adding one with the `methods=["POST"]` decorator like your `/json` endpoint.